# Ignore annotation in super class for ObjectMapper

Tags: java, annotations, jackson

Lets say I have the classes:

```
public class A {
   @ApiModelProperty(
        hidden = true
    )
  private String text;
  // GET + SET
}


public class B extends A {
  private String name;
  // GET + SET
}
```

I would like the ObjectMapper NOT to ignore property "text" when creating the JSON of class B

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer: to my knowledge this isn't possible, and also doesn't make sense conceptually.

That annotation is a very *explicit* mechanism to **express** a certain semantical meaning.

I assume you are saying: when A objects are serialized, or C objects are serialized (C also extending A, just like B) ... then *text* should show up. If so: consider using two **different** base classes then. Because you want to do *two* ***different*** things here. Then make that explicit. Insted of looking for some dirty hack to override that "override" you explicitly put into your code!

Comment: I agree that it is not optimal, but I'm not in controll of the super class, and it implements a lot of logic I'd rather not replicate.

Comment: As said: I am not aware of a detour here. And you know: when people put up requirements that are impossible to met, then the correct answer is: challenge the people asking you to do things that are not possible. Worst case you would have to write your own custom deserializer.